# djnago with google smtp [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: django, smtp

in my settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.google.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '*********@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '************'
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

in views.py

```
def sendEmail(request, order_id):
    order = Inventory_Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    orderitems = Order_Item.objects.filter(order=order)

    try:
        subject = f"Wiss - New Order {order}"
        to = [f'{order.customer.email}']
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        order_information = {
            'order':order,
            'orderitems':orderitems
        }
        message = get_template('Inventory_Management/email.html').render(order_information)
        msg = EmailMessage(subject, message, to=to, from_email=from_email)
        msg.content_subtype = 'html'
        msg.send(fail_silently=False)
        print(f'message sent to {order.customer.email}!')
    except IOError as e:
        print('Failed')
        print(e)
        return e
```

when i call the function i get the following error  [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed, What's The Problem? Any Help is Appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

It really wasn't working and then i found out that it should be smtp.googlemail.com instead of smtp.google.com, which is quite surprising cz the website i first used to implement this used smtp.google.com. anyways it workes now!

Answer (score 0):

Use `smtp.gmail.com` as `EMAIL_HOST`

From [Googel support](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en):

**Step 2: Change SMTP & other settings in your email client**

Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server > smtp.gmail.com

Other necessary settings are also mentioned